# Text and images become blurry after exchanging monitor on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I exchanged one monitor on Windows 10 for testing purposes. It was a smaller monitor, so my system adjusted well to the new monitor.

Now I replaced my original monitor and the graphics were initially on small screen size. I changed the screen resolution to match the size using graphic options.

Now it's fitting the screen but the text and images are blurry like the image below.

[image: Blurry Screen Demo]

What should I do?

Comment: Your screenshot looks perfectly fine. Are you sure the screen resolution you set is the native resolution of your new display?

Comment: yes my native display which warning also suggest is diff then what I have set.

Comment: If I use a specific resolution, then I am able to get the perfect result, but it is far less then waht is suggested by the warning